# Latex Tikz externalize with shell escape does not work

Tags: memory, latex, tikz

Im trying to use the Tikz externalize, because for some tikz pictures the file gets to big and exceeds the memory size. I found a lot of other topics with similar problems, but non of the solutions worked for me or I did not implement them well enough. 
I'm using Winedt 10.2(also tried Winedt 9)
Mixtex 2.9

The structure of the report:

Final_Report.tex

--Layout.tex

--Simulation_model.tex

----plot_baseunit.tex(Tikz picture)

Final_Report.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\input{./Lay_out/layout.tex}`
\begin{document}
\input{./Chapters/Simulation_Model/Simulation_Model.tex}
\end{document}
```

layout.tex

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows,fit,positioning,shapes,chains, plotmarks,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc,patterns,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/,shell escape=-enable-write18]
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
%Standard figure dimension
\newcommand{\plotx}{12.0cm}
\newcommand{\ploty}{6.0cm}
\newcommand{\plotysub}{3.0cm} %y-dimension of seperate subplots
%Subplot dimensions (2 plots wide subplots)
\newcommand{\subtwoplotx}{5.25cm}
\newcommand{\subtwoploty}{4.5cm}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, node distance=2.0cm, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=2.0cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
```

Simulation_model.tex

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\input{./figures/plot_baseunit.tex}
}%
\caption{The throughput and cycle time of the production line plotted against the process time of a base unit workstation, as bottleneck of the system. The horizontal dotted lines represent the designed throughput and cycle time of the Honda/JLR(green) and Audi/Porsche roof systems(purple).}
\label{fig:Base_unit_through}
\end{figure}
```

When I try to run this using PDFTeXify it gives the following error.

```
   (figures/plot_baseunit.tex
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname 
"figures/Final_Report-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Final_Report}\input{Final_Report}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error-interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "figures/Final_Report-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{Final_Report}\input{Final_Report}"
```

did NOT result in a usable output file 
    'figures/Final_Report-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). 
    Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
     Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe  the command simply failed?
     Error messages can be found in 'figures/Final_Report-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

If I just press enter the right figures come out, but this does not work for large files and then the memory size is exceeded.

Thanks in advance!.